# Convert string numbers to Array C#

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a `string str = "012345";` I want to convert it to an array which would look like `intAry = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. Any ideas?

I tried like this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
   intAry[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
}
```

But what went to array are like 48, 49, etc. Which correct method should I use here?

Comment: Just minus the ASCII code of '0', which is 48 (in decimal).  In ASCII and Unicode, digits are consecutive in sequence.  This is a pretty standard trick when using "old" programming languages (e.g. C).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        intAry[i] = str[i] - '0';
```

**Update**

Or as LINQ:

```
var array = str.Select(ch => ch - '0').ToArray();
```

Comment: I think you mean str[i] - '0'

Comment: Should that not be `str[i] - '0'`?

Comment: you menat intAry[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i] - '0');

Comment: Yup. str[i] - '0' gave me what I wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

How about this.

```
  string source = "12345";
   Int32[] array=source.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

but remember every character within **source** should be convertible to an **Integer**

Answer (score 0):

48, 49, etc. went in because that is the ASCII value of '0'.  If you subtract '0' *from the char*, it will give you the correct integer.  No convert required.

```
intAry[i] = str[i] - '0';
```