# How to obtain an integer array from a string

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have gone through this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729472/convert-string-numbers-to-array-c-sharp#). But this is not solving my problem. Let's say I have a string:

```
var aString = "0 -1 12 456 -512";
```

I want to convert this string to an int array like:

```
var convertedArray = [0, -1, 12, 456, -512];
```

How should I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: `aString.Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var stringNumbers = aString.Split(' ');
var numbers = new int[stringNumbers.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < stringNumbers.Length; i++)
    numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stringNumbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var convertedArray = Array.ConvertAll(aString.Split(' '), int.Parse);
```

Comment: Code only answer are not answer.